# Set debugfs pager

Tags: bash, pager, debugfs

I do not want [pager](/questions/tagged/pager) to clear screen when using [debugfs](/questions/tagged/debugfs).

Have tried things like, as per [man for debugfs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/debugfs.8.html#ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLES):

```
export PAGER='less -FX'
debugfs foo bar

export DEBUGFS_PAGER='less -FX'
debugfs foo bar

DEBUGFS_PAGER='less -FX' debugfs foo bar

PAGER='less -FX' debugfs foo bar

DEBUGFS_PAGER='less -FX' PAGER='less -FX' debugfs foo bar
```

but commands, for example `ls`, still show a full screen page which are cleared after `q`.

What I should do is?

---

#### *Update:*

As per comment by [thrig](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265586/set-debugfs-pager#comment459541_265586) I created the file `.terminfo/xterm-nopager.terminfo` from a copy of `infocmp`, modified it to exclude `rmcup` and `smcup` and ran:

```
tic ~/.terminfo/xterm-nopager.terminfo
```

This *works* (besides, obviously, from options to less like `F` not being honored.)

Is there a way to do this without modifying terminfo? I do not like to modify essentials like that on a global scale. (That is; I am not sure if I should care or not, so I do.)

Is this a bug in debugfs, as `man` say one can override, or is it a consequence of other external environment? Is there a way to do this per command?

Comment: Probably actually a terminal question about the evil alternate screen that so infuriatingly blanks the docs you were just looking at -  http://shallowsky.com/linux/noaltscreen.html

Comment: @thrig: Thanks. That worked. But *man* for debugfs states one can set pager manually. I'll explore a bit further.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, *don't* use a pager `:-)` This may not be what you want, since it doesn't set a pager, but the following works for me (in `bash`, in a fresh terminal), with values set accordingly (you can of course one-line this):

```
INODE='01234567'        # replace with valid inode# for some file
DEVICE='/dev/whatever'  # replace with valid device for that inode
# your distro might not require `sudo`, mine does
sudo debugfs -R 'stat <'"${INODE}"'>' "${DEVICE}" 2>/dev/null | tee
```

I get `sudo`-prompted, then the data writes to `stdout` normally, as if unpaged--particularly, the screen does *not* get cleared. This is what I want; YMMV, HTH.